# Adding column names in XTS and changing dates in XTS

Tags: r, time-series, xts

The xts looks like:

```
An ‘xts’ object on 1970-01-02 05:30:00/1976-03-29 05:30:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:2279, 1] 0.295 0.316 0.315 0.301 0.292 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  Original class: 'double'  
  xts Attributes: NULL
```

This XTS is generated through another code and does not have column names as shown by

```
dimnames(cor_BG_xts)
[[1]]
NULL
[[2]]
NULL
colnames(cor_BG_xts)
NULL
```

How can one add column names to xts. I tried searing stack overflow but I get the solutions for data.frame instead of xts. Do, I need to first convert it to df and then name the columns. 
Also, the xts takes the dates like `1970-01-02 05:30:00`. How can one change the xts say `12/1/2009  12:00:00`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first create a reproducible example:

```
library(xts)

dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2018-11-19"), as.Date("2018-11-23"), by = "day")
numbers <- 1:5

my_xts <- xts(numbers, dates)
my_xts
                    [,1]
2018-11-19 05:30:00    1
2018-11-20 05:30:00    2
2018-11-21 05:30:00    3
2018-11-22 05:30:00    4
2018-11-23 05:30:00    5
```

Now setting (renaming) a column name is not difficult, either use `names`, `colnames`, or `setNames`.

```
names(my_xts) <- "new_column_name"
# setNames / colnames works as well.
# my_xts <- setNames(my_xts, "new_column_name")
# colnames(my_xts) <- "new_column_name"
# 
my_xts
                    new_column_name
2018-11-19 05:30:00               1
2018-11-20 05:30:00               2
2018-11-21 05:30:00               3
2018-11-22 05:30:00               4
2018-11-23 05:30:00               5
```

Changing the index format, use `indexFormat`. You can use any date time format that is mentioned in the details of `?strptime`.

```
indexFormat(my_xts) <- "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
my_xts
                    new_column_name
19/11/2018 05:30:00               1
20/11/2018 05:30:00               2
21/11/2018 05:30:00               3
22/11/2018 05:30:00               4
23/11/2018 05:30:00               5
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer. My problem is that the time series is creating the time stamps (starting index from 1970) by itself. Now I have understood that it is because that I should pass the xts to the function which generates this xts object. On passing xts to the function it takes the required time stamps. Many thanks for the answer on renaming the xts columns.